# How to add Users in Identity entity called AspNetUserRoles table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Hi Folks I have a brainfart moment, I have been struggling for this for last week, and I think this is the time to ask for your opinion. So what I am trying to achieve here is to insert the record in AspNetUserRoles, but somehow I am getting an error saying UserId is null.

NOTE: I am able to store user in ASpNetUser, AspNetRole. So that means IdentityDbContext might not needed.

so this is the point where i am getting error

```
await multiTierDbContext1.AspNetUserRoles.AddAsync(userRole);
```

The error is shown below in screenshot I attached the screenshot below. Please help me to achieve this.
the code for Register a User

```
[HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserRequest user)
        {
         //var userName=   userManager.FindByNameAsync("Shubham.maini@bhn.com").Result;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                    var users = new AspNetUser {Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Email =user.Email , UserName = user.Username, ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), LockoutEnabled=false, NormalizedEmail =user.Email, NormalizedUserName =user.Username,Discriminator="abc"};
                    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(users, user.Password);
                    if(!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                    return BadRequest(result);
                    }
                
                    if(user.Roles.Any())
                {
                    foreach(var role in user.Roles)
                    {
                        var roleExist = _provider.GetService<IRoleStore<AspNetRole>>();
                        var resultRow = new AspNetRole()
                        {
                            Name = role
                        };
                        /*var resultS = await roleExist.CreateAsync(res, CancellationToken.None);*/
                      
                        var roleExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
                       
                        if(!roleExists)
                        {
                            resultRow.Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                            resultRow.NormalizedName = role.ToUpper();
                          var roleResult = await roleExist.CreateAsync(resultRow, CancellationToken.None);                           
                        }
                        var userRequest = new AspNetUser()
                        {
                            UserName = user.Username,
                        };
                        var userss= await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Username);
                        var response=await roleExist.FindByNameAsync("Admin", CancellationToken.None);
                        
                        if(userss.Id!=null! && response!=null)
                        {
                            var userRole = new AspNetUserRole()
                            {
                                UserId =userss.Id,
                                RoleId = response.Id,
                            };
                           await multiTierDbContext1.AspNetUserRoles.AddAsync(userRole);
                            multiTierDbContext1.SaveChanges();               
                        }                       
                        //var userToRole = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userss, "ADMIN");
                        /* var userRole = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(userss, role);
                         if (!userRole)
                         {
                             var userToRole = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userss, "Admin");
                         }*/
                    }
                }

                    
                    /*                var ApplicationUsers = new ApplicationUser { Email = user.Email, UserName = user.UserName };
                                multiTierDbContext.ApplicationUsers.Add(ApplicationUsers);
                                multiTierDbContext.SaveChanges();*/
                return Ok(result);
                
            }
            return Ok();
          
        }
```

The Db context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
                   .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");


        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
             .HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });


        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
           .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
           .WithMany(r => r.Users)
           .UsingEntity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(
               ur => ur.HasOne<AspNetRole>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired(),
               ur => ur.HasOne<AspNetUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId).IsRequired() );

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.AspNetRoles");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.AspNetUsers");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);
            entity.Property(e => e.Discriminator).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.Roles).WithMany(p => p.Users)
                 .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                     "AspNetUserRole",
                     r => r.HasOne<AspNetRole>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleId"),
                     l => l.HasOne<AspNetUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId"),
                     j =>
                     {
                         j.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId");
                         j.HasIndex(new[] { "RoleId" }, "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId");
                     });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaim>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "IX_User_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .HasMaxLength(128)
                .HasColumnName("User_Id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserClaims)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogin>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey }).HasName("PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "IX_UserId");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasMaxLength(128);
            entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);
            entity.Property(e => e.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserLogins)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MigrationHistory>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.MigrationId, e.ContextKey }).HasName("PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory");

            entity.ToTable("__MigrationHistory");

            entity.Property(e => e.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(150);
            entity.Property(e => e.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(300);
            entity.Property(e => e.ProductVersion).HasMaxLength(32);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
```

these are extended classes created under same

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApi.Database.Models;
  /*  [Table("AspNetUsers")]*/
    public partial class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
    {
       public ICollection<AspNetUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WebApi.Database.Models;
    public partial class AspNetUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
    public override string RoleId { get; set; }

    public override string UserId { get; set; }

    public AspNetUser User { get; set; }

    public AspNetRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApi.Database.Models;
 /*   [Table("AspNetRoles")]*/
    public partial class AspNetRole : IdentityRole
    {

    public ICollection<AspNetUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

I tried different ways to achieve this, I used `userManager.AddToRoles()` 
method but it is also throwing the same error then i tried to achieve this using direct saving the entries in the table, its showing the same error, I tried to use the Partial classes of same name and including the same namespace of Models original folder created by scaffold-database command, the reason why I selected partial classes of same name because I don't want to make any change in original entity classes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XClOu.png)

The error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'AspNetUserRole' because its primary key property 'UserId' is null.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityStateAsync(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintActionAsync(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraphAsync[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`3 handleNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraphAsync(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.AddAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApi.Controllers.PersonController.Register(UserRequest user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: just check the if condition which might be wrong syntax might causing error.  `if(userss.Id!=null! && response!=null)`